# How to add multi recaptcha in a page

Tags: 8, javascript, captcha

I have some custom form in a page ( sign/signup),first I try render them with  google API instruction

> Paste this snippet before the closing  tag on your HTML template:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>>
```

> Paste this snippet at the end of the  where you want the reCAPTCHA widget to appear:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key_api"></div>
```

everything was ok for only one form, but recaptcha in another form not rendered.

I search for a solution and [found How do I show multiple recaptchas on a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241947/how-do-i-show-multiple-recaptchas-on-a-single-page)

Then I'm trying to implement it with Drupal structure.what I do is

part of  **mytheme_libraries.yml** file

```
global-script:
  js:
    https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit: { type: external, minified: true ,attributes: { defer: true, async: true} }
    js/myload-recaptcha.js: {}
```

and **myload-recaptcha.js** file

```
Drupal.behaviors.myrecaptcha = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        (function ($) {
            alert('Hello,I am fine');
            var CaptchaCallback = function () {
                $('.g-recaptcha').each(function (index, el) {
                    grecaptcha.render(el, {'sitekey': 'my_key'});
                });
                console.log(grecaptcha);
            };
        })(jQuery);
    }
};
```

and some  part of  `header.html.twig`

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha-signup" ></div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha-signin" ></div>
                </div>
```

**alert fire correctly** and it mean file loaded correctly, I take look and  js files, also  `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explici` exists in loaded js files.

**where is the problem and how can I render two Captcha in Drupal 8 theme  programmatically ?**